# В .net winforms не получается нарисовать отрезок из одного угла формы в другой

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi

Почему в .net winforms не получается нарисовать отрезок из одного угла формы в другой? 
Следующий код:

```
 private void Display_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
    this.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(Pens.Green, 0, 0, Width, Height);
 }
```

как я думал должен нарисовать нечто такое (спасибо paint):
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, получаю следующее 
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Передаваемые размеры верны. Не понимаю в чем может быть дело.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мне кажется, при прорисовке, вы не учитываете заголовок окна. Попробуйте так

```
private void Display_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var rect = this.ClientRectangle;
    this.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(Pens.Green, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height);
}
```